# Limiting the length of a toString return

Tags: java, tostring

I need to make a program that returns an error list in a file.

The problem I'm having is that it returns the String in one big line, with the following toString method:

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Resultat{" +
                "status=" + complet + "\n" + ", erreur=" + erreur +
                '}';
    }
```

Is there a way to get a return of the specific String in restricted length of 80 length, then skip line?

For exemple:

```
Apple
Green
```

instead of(of course the line would be considerably longer in that case).

```
Apple Green
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex, capturing groups of 80 characters, `(.{80})` and replacing them with the captured group followed by a newline `$1\n`.

Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    final String oldString = "...";
    // TODO - build old toString here...
    return oldString.replaceAll("(.{80})", "$1\n");
}
```

Not saying this is a fast way (and it sounds like something whatever you're *formatting* the `String` for should handle, not the `toString` method itself...), but it should do the trick.